# Most efficient way of storing objects with corresponding indices

Tags: c#, list, performance, dictionary, hashtable

I want to store a collection of Points, which are objects of the class `Point`. (`Point` contains properties as `positionX`, `positionY`, `electricalPotential`, etc.)
Each of them should have an index `i`, but the don't need to be ordered in any way.
This is why I used a dictionary `Dictionary<int, Point> meshpoints` in the first place.

**First Question:**
Is a dictionary the most efficient way of storing my data if I only want to store the object with a certain index/key, especially if it comes to performance issues as adding, searching and looping for each element?

**Second Question:**
If I want to add a new Point, how do I get the "next" free key? Like if I have dictionary with the hash-keys `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, how do I get the `5` for the next item-key?

*Option 1:* `meshpoints.Keys.Max()` and `meshpoints.Keys.Last()` take a lot of time in my tests.

```
Dictionary<int, string> meshpoints = new Dictionary<int, string>();

meshpoints.Add(meshpoints.Keys.Max() + 1, "itemA");

meshpoints.Add(meshpoints.Keys.Max() + 1, "itemB");
```

*Option 2:* Creating a seperate variable `counter` is pretty fast in my performance test, but is it really the most elegant way? I mean, you always have a carry a seperate integer value with dictionary to all methods, etc. ...

```
Dictionary<int, string> meshpoints = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int counter = 0;

meshpoints.Add(counter, "itemA");
counter++;

meshpoints.Add(counter, "itemB");
counter++;
```

*Option 3:* `meshpoints.Count()` won't work, when I also delete items at any point.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Create a separate variable `counter`. Or use `meshpoints.Count` for the next item if you won't be deleting items from the dictionary. But if you'll never remove them, just use `List` instead of Dictionary and make the index the identifier. If `meshpoints[0]` will never be deleted, `meshpoints[3]` is always the same object. If you may delete them, use a dictionary and a counter variable.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Should we not also consider random access besides a "Delete" operation? In case you care about performance and random access, I would assume you should still go for a class storing points in a Dictionary.

Comment: @vonludi [`List<T>`'s index operator is a wrapper around an array indexing operation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,189). It's not slow. Are you thinking of a linked list?

Comment: An `index` has not identity semantics. The index of an item can change, if another item located before it is removed. Maybe you mean `id` instead of `index`?

Comment: You could generate a GUID, to use as the Key.

Comment: Can you have multiple points with the same coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like having two separate variables, then make a new structure to bind them together:

```
struct MeshPointContainer
{
    private int _counter = 0;
    private List<Point> _pts = new List<Point>();

    public int Add(Point pt) {
        _pts.Add(pt);
        return ++counter;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var meshPoints = new MeshPointContainer();
meshPoints.Add(new Point(-1f));
```

This will be a little more complicated if you want to be able to remove points, but so far you have not indicated that you do.

Comment: is this also possible with a generic list-type? so I want to have a `List<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dictionary since what you want to do can be done with a list.

Because you use the `Count + 1` as new ID, you can add an autogenerated ID to the Point class and it is a better design:

```
public class Point
{ 
  static private int NextID;

  int ID { get; }
  public Point()
  {
    ID = NextID++;
  }
}

List<Point> meshPoints = new List<Point>();

var meshPointA = new Point();
var meshPointB = new Point();
var meshPointC = new Point();

meshPoints.Add(meshPointA);
meshPoints.Add(meshPointB);
meshPoints.Add(meshPointC);

var meshPoint = meshPoints.Where(p => p.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault();
```

With that, you will never have duplicated ID nor conflicts while adding, inserting and removing objects.

With option1, Max does not provide speed performance.

With option3, using Count will cause these problems: if you add 4 points next delete the two first then add one, this last will have ID as 3 while the two remaining have 3 and 4 as ID... so the option2 is better.

If you want a dictionary, you can do the same thing by creating a class that embedd an internal dictionary, that has the NextID, and that offers the methods you want to provide like Add, Remove, ContainsX,  IDs (Items.Keys), Points (Items.Values) and so on (all you want to manage this specialized collection):

```
public class PointsDictionary : IEnumerable<Point>
{
  private readonly Dictionary<int, Point> Items = new Dictionary<int, Point>();

  private int NextID;

  public Point this[int index]
  {
    get { return Items.ContainsKey(index) ? Items[index] : null; }
    set { ... }
  }

  public Dictionary<int, Point>.KeyCollection IDs
  {
    get { return Items.Keys; }
  }

  public Dictionary<int, Point>.ValueCollection Points
  {
    get { return Items.Values; }
  }

  public int Add(Point point)
  {
    int index = NextID++;
    Items.Add(index, point);
    return index;
  }

  ...

}
```

So here, you will have a strong and clean design.

Answer (score 0):

This question has too many variables to be properly answered. If data has to be stored as you mention

> with a certain index/key,

that key of access has to be known to the accessor...otherwise why would one want to use a dictionary with integers as the key?

> how do I get the "next" free key?

One is not guaranteed uniqueness with [Object.GetHashCode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8), and it should be overridden by yourself to create a proper hash, but one can do something like this

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, PointIt>();

var p1 = new PointIt() { PositionX=1, PositionY=2,  ElectricalPotential=999.99};
var p2 = new PointIt() { PositionX=1, PositionY=2,  ElectricalPotential=999.99};

myDict.Add(p1.GetHashCode(), p1);
myDict.Add(p2.GetHashCode(), p2);

myDict.ToList()
      .ForEach(itm => Console.WriteLine($"Key ({itm.Key}) Value {itm.Value}"));
```

With output such as

```
Key (23832771) Value X:1 Y:2 Potential:999.99
Key (44512918) Value X:1 Y:2 Potential:999.99
```

---

```
public class PointIt
{
    public int PositionX { get; set; }
    public int PositionY { get; set; }
    public double ElectricalPotential { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"X:{PositionX} Y:{PositionY} Potential:{ElectricalPotential}";
}
```